# what are the components you can install on RHEL?

Tags: rhel-5, components

I just got a question from a customer(actually from a customer to my manager then to me) and he is asking the following question:  What are the components that were installed with RHEL?  It may sound like a silly question but to me it sounds vague.  The main thing I am thinking about now is during install you can select three components: webserver software development and virtualisation.  Could they be asking fro something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/root/anaconda-ks.cfg` is a [Kickstart](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Kickstart) file suitable for reconstructing the system, which happens to enumerate the groups and packages selected during install in the `%packages` section.